# Magento 2.3 : I can't login to admin after making changes to Admin Base URL

Tags: magento2.3, admin-login

I made modifications to the Admin Base URL section, the login page changed but the form is available (See Image). So when I login in using

```
Chrome : I get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"
IE     : There were too many redirections.
Error Code: INET_E_REDIRECT_FAILED"
```

and in the url the admin url appears twice eg. admin_Fra/admin_fra ...

when I change the admin url in env.php the old one is still seen eg. admin_Fra/admin_new ...

I have cleared cache, removed http to https redirect in .htaccess, reset both web/secure/use_in_frontend and    web/secure/use_in_adminhtml to 0 but no change,

I will appreciate any timely support as I cant make any transactions currently.

How else can I reverse the settings without admin access.

[image]

Comment: in Stores>configuration>admin>Admin Base URL

Comment: it seems that your static view files were not deployed, try to redeploy static view files

Comment: Anything jump out in your log files?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the mySQL database, you can try this query, it will show the two urls you have configured for HTTP and HTTPS protocols:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path like '%base_url%'
```

and then update the values directly in that table, using sql UPDATE statement

Answer (score 0):

Refresh cache from commandline.

php bin/magento c:c